# how to create row in angular js?

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to make a row which is displayed in image .Actually my circle is not on right side and my “P” is not getting background color.Here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/qIz2rFgW8n3J92evCRTd?p=preview

can we give row height in percentage ?
actually I need my row should look like as shown in image

```
![<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Ionic Swipe Down</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/contrib/ionic-contrib-swipecards/ionic.swipecards.js?v=5"></script>

</head>
<style>
    .brd {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
<body ng-app="">

<div class="list card">

    <div class="item item-avatar">
       <div style="border: 1px solid red;float: left;background: gray;">P </div>
        <h2>16000389</h2>
        <p>RutherFord & Alfanso Company Lmt</p>
        <div style="border: 1px solid black;float: left;background: green;border-radius: 100%;width: 50px;height: 50px">650</div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is a CSS question, change your tags to get a quick answer

Comment: done ..I added css3 Question ..if you have some knowledge please post it

Answer (score 0):

Update Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z8w97NgD15rwuKjnmr05?p=preview

Edit: In light of the responsive requirement I have changed the plunker to use viewport settings. This will take up 100% of the width AND set the height of the items inside it to remain in proportion. As for the text I'm not sure you can do that with pure css.

```
<div class="">

<div class="" style="height: 30vw; position:relative; width: 100%;">
  <div style="float: left;background: gray; height:100%; width: 10%; text-align:center;">
    <div style=" position:relative; top:40%;">P</div>
  </div>
  <h2>16000389</h2>
  <p>RutherFord & Alfanso Company Lmt</p>

  <div style="border: 1px solid black;float: right;background: green;border-radius: 100%;width: 20vw; height: 20vw;position:absolute; top:20%; text-align:center; right:10%">
    <div style=" position:relative; top:30%;">650</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I assume you will be moving all this inline css to separate files though...

Comment: It's not clear if you need full width rows or if the circles will be different sizes etc. My solution works for the image you have shown though.

Comment: your anser is incorrect ..It is not responsive and please check to smaller and bigger window

Comment: please check myQuestion it responsive for all browser width and height .but it not responsive

Comment: Do you require 100% row width? In what way would you like it to be responsive?

Comment: yes I want 100% width and it will work on all  screen resolution

Comment: As Now  a days all HTML is responsive which working on all device or all screen resolution

Comment: Ok I've updated the plunker with 100% width row. I'm not sure I follow what you mean by multiple resolutions. Are you seeing a problem with that solution?

Comment: Actually This html will run on all iphone , tablets , or ipad , android phone .So it will look fine if it run on all devices