# why P tag not taking whole height of row?

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

could you please tell me why why P tag not taking whole height of row ?Actually I have p tag in my row in which the text is “P” only having background color light blue .It is not taking whole height of row   as shown in image ?
 I will try to explain more in other words .

- I am trying to make a row as shown in image .it have “P” text  in image “left” one .It is not taking whole height of row as shown in image
- I have one circle on right side it is having some text inside “650” it .it is not displaying on centre why ?

plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/ilmNaeyjFZCcSnb2PWcO?p=preview

```
.bg {
    background: lightgray;
    position: relative;
}
.ptag {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -7%;
    width: 7%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
    color: white;
}
.circle{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: green;
    margin-top: -7%;
    color:black!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.ptag {
    position: absolute;
    top:0; /* set at top */
    margin-left: -7%;
    width: 7%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
.circle{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: green;
    margin-top: -7%;
    color:black!important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px; /* same as height */
}
```

[**Plunker Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/z2IhxDtUAFkTA3YyYKPh?p=preview)

Comment: please check image .."P" having background color blue not taking full height as given in image

Comment: correct 90%.I have one Question is it responsive ? mean is it work on all screen resolution ..secondly "P" is have some margin in your demo but in mage there is no left margin ..can we give zero margin from left

Comment: I just used your code...Frankly I would not have done it the way you have....but test it out and play. http://plnkr.co/edit/thI2W82Qp9GkCXVVokM9?p=preview   Is it responsive?...not with fixed pixel values.

Comment: how you will do if you will get this ? I am not using any pixel mean static value .I am taking in %

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82085/discussion-between-user944513-and-paulie-d).

Comment: Thanks but I think I will leave this here.

Answer (score 1):

I already gave you a solution here: [how to create row in angular js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157713/how-to-create-row-in-angular-js/31158471#31158471)

In the other question you appear to be asking for the row div and all of it's children to dynamically size based upon the screen resolution.

In the plunker you did not give external css hence the solution I pasted there and here has the css inline. The below will make the div containing P be 100% height along with the rest of the content being 'dynamic' in that they maintain their aspect ratios on different resolutions screens.

Including an updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z8w97NgD15rwuKjnmr05?p=preview

```
<div class="" style="height: 30vw; position:relative; width: 100%;">
  <div style="float: left;background: gray; height:100%; width: 10%; text-align:center;">
    <div style=" position:relative; top:40%;">P</div>
  </div>
  <h2>16000389</h2>
  <p>RutherFord & Alfanso Company Lmt</p>

  <div style="border: 1px solid black;float: right;background: green;border-radius: 100%;width: 20vw; height: 20vw;position:absolute; top:20%; text-align:center; right:10%">
  <div style=" position:relative; top:30%;">650</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use text-align: center and line-height to center the texts inside div.

Your corrected CSS here:

```
.ptag {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -7%;
    width: 7%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background: lightblue;
    color: white;
}
.circle{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: green;
    margin-top: -7%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color:black!important;
}
```